# Dynamically load a Class and invoke a method in Java

Tags: java, class, reflection, methods, invoke

Lets say i want to dynamically load a class in java and call it's `start()` (has no params) method:

```
Class<?> c = Class.forName("AbuseMe");
c.getMethod("start").invoke(c.newInstance());
```

Would this be a good/safe way to do it?

Comment: If it is working and you are catching exceptions then it is safe :)

Comment: @duffymo the code works, but i was not sure if my approach is safe. Especially if it's ok to use the newInstance() method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks good to me.

If you're doing a lot of reflection-related code you might look at Apache [Beanutils](http://commons.apache.org/beanutils/) or Apache [OGNL](http://commons.apache.org/ognl/) or something similar.