# How to infer method of T from Class<T>

Tags: java, generics, enums

I have an enum which is implements an interface. Enum:

```
enum MyEnum implements MyInterface {
    ONE, TWO, THREE;

    @Override
    public MyEnum getFirst() {
        return ONE;
    }
}
```

Interface:

```
interface MyInterface<T extends Enum<T>> {
    T getFirst();
}
```

Also I have a generic class with bounds:

```
class MyClass <T extends Enum<T> & MyInterface> {
   private T firstElement;
   private Class<T> enumType;

   MyClass (Class<T> enumType) {
      this.enumType = enumType;
   }
}
```

So the main idea is to pass any `enum` (which is implements `MyIterface`) into constructor and then work with its constants. And this works for me. But also I want to store this first element into `firstElement` private field. I tried something like this:

```
firstElement = ((MyInterface)enumType).getFirst();
```

But still no success. I can't cast `java.lang.Class<T>` to `MyInterface`. Any ideas how to achieve this? Thanks in advance!

*UPDATE*: My problem is not about how to take the first enum constant. I know about `.ordinal()` and `.values()[0];`. I want to create reusable generic class and use it with any enums, marked by some interface. 
Ok, let it not be `getFirst()` method. Let it be `getDefault()`

Comment: @ΦXocę웃Пepeúpaツ all enums extend that class, it does make sense :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I invoke a Java method when given the method name as a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/160970/how-do-i-invoke-a-java-method-when-given-the-method-name-as-a-string)

Comment: enumType is of Class type, it will not have your enum method. Only MyEnum.ONE, MyEnum.TWO so forth will have that method available.

Comment: also see this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11594797/dynamically-load-a-class-and-invoke-a-method-in-java

Comment: @niceman I don't think he needs reflection API here, he is trying to make it generic in a clean way.

Comment: @Sikorski hmm OP is missing the T in `& MyInterface`, when that is included I guess `firstelement.getFirst()` will work

Comment: by the way what do `MyInterface` and `MyClass` represent ? is it just for curiosity sake ?

Comment: @niceman, I just want to create a generic class to work with different enums, marked by some interface

Comment: Don't use raw types! Give a try of your code but without the raw types.

Comment: and what would that generic class rerpesent ? like is it a `Person` ? a `ModuleManager` ? a Utility class maybe ? clearly we have [an XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) here

Comment: Do you need to get the class of the enum as well? Or is it enough to access  `MyInterface` methods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you could use `Supplier<T>` as an argument for your constructor instead of `Class<T>`:

```
class MyClass<T extends Enum<T> & MyInterface<T>>  {
    private T firstElement;
    private Class<T> enumType;

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    MyClass (Supplier<T> enumSupplier) {
        T actualEnum = enumSupplier.get();
        this.enumType = (Class<T>) actualEnum.getClass();
        this.firstElement = actualEnum.getFirst();
    }
}
```

That cast throws a warning, but it can be safely suppressed, since `Supplier<T>` will return an instance of `T`, and `T` is both `Enum<T>` and `MyInterface<T>`, so the class of `actualEnum` will always be `Class<T>`.

I would like to suggest you a few corrections: as `MyInterface` is generic, you should always use it along with a generic type (this is why I've declared `MyClass` as `MyClass<T extends Enum<T> & MyInterface<T>>`). The same goes for `MyEnum`: it should be defined as `MyEnum implements MyInterface<MyEnum>`.

With the above changes in place, you can now create an instance of `MyClass` as follows:

```
MyClass<MyEnum> myClass = new MyClass<>(() -> MyEnum.THREE); // Or ONE or TWO

System.out.println(myClass.firstElement); // ONE
```

Answer (score 1):

From your context I think you need `getFirst()` because you want to get the first value of a enum. However, you don't need `getFirst()` at all. All you need is this:

```
class <T extends Enum<T> & MyInterface> MyClass {
   private T firstElement;
   private Class<T> enumType;

   MyClass (Class<T> enumType) {
      this.enumType = enumType;
      firstElement = enumType.getEnumConstants()[0];
   }
}
```

You can just remove all those `getFirst()` in all of your classes.

Comment: @niceman Uh, I'm afraid the OP may cry that `MyInterface` is a marker interface and can't be removed. Fo example [CopyOption](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/CopyOption.html).

Answer (score 1):

You can call `getFirst` only on an enum object which implements `MyInterface` but not on its class. You can write:

```
firstElement = enumType.getEnumConstants()[0].getFirst();
```

Comment: but since enums are ordered I don't understand why you want a `getFirst()` method at all.

Comment: Thanks, but I know about `.values()[0]`, `.ordinal()` and `.getEnumConstants()`. My question is not about how to get the first enum constant. It's about generics. I'll update my post.

Comment: @YevhenDanchenko check my answer: `enumType.getEnumConstants()[0]` is only used to get from `Class<T>` to a `T` object and then invoke `getFirst()` (or `getDefault()`) on this object.

Comment: I get error with this solution: `java.lang.Enum cannot be converted to T`

Comment: @YevhenDanchenko because you did not add `<T>` to `MyInterface` in the declaration of `MyClass`: it should read `class MyClass<T extends Enum<T> & MyInterface<T>>`

Answer (score 0):

```
interface MyInterface {
    MyInterface getFirst();

    MyInterface[] getConstants();
}

enum MyEnum implements MyInterface {
    ONE, TWO, THREE;

    @Override
    public MyInterface getFirst() {
        return ONE;
    }

    @Override
    public MyInterface[] getConstants() {
        return new MyInterface[] {ONE, TWO, THREE};
    }
}

class MyClass {
   private MyInterface firstElement;

   MyClass (MyInterface enumType) {
      this.firstElement = enumType.getFirst();
   }
}
```

So, using the above design I think you can "pass any enum (which is implements MyInterface) into constructor and then work with its constants."

Comment: My point is that, when you use some attribute like "enumType", you're not using Interfaces properly. Because, at some point you would have to write something like " if (enumType == SomeType) " or if (enumType SomeType), and those don't seem to be a good design. Interfaces are used mainly to replace this 'if else' logic (or switch) for type checking.

Comment: Thanks. It seems it makes sense. Perhaps I have problems with architecture.