# Java invoke class to call method inside

Tags: java, invoke

I have a problem. In my code I have the following line:

```
HashMap<String, String> strategyResponse = strategy_005.run(runDateTimeLocal);
```

This function is inside the `strategy_005` class:

```
public class strategy_005 {

    public static HashMap<String, String> run(Integer i) {

        HashMap<String, String> output = new HashMap<>();
        output.put("Response", i.toString());
        return output;

    }

}
```

I am not calling the function in the `strategy_005` class, but in my `MainClass`. The problem I have is that the `005` part in the class is dynamic, so I have multiple classes from `strategy_001` to `strategy_015`.

Here is the code from my `MainClass`:

```
public class MainClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        for (int i = 1; i <= 15; i++) {
            
            // Call every "strategy_0(i)" run() method
            HashMap<String, String> strategyResponse = strategy_005.run(i);
            System.out.println(strategyResponse.get("Response"));

        }

    }

}
```

I know how to invoke methods from a class by name, but I don't know how to invoke a class and then call the method that I do know. The only thing I found that is close to what I want is this:
[Creating an instance using the class name and calling constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6094575/creating-an-instance-using-the-class-name-and-calling-constructor)

Unfortunatly this topic is about calling the constructor, but I want to call a custom method.
Please let me know how I can achieve this!

Comment: If you want the methods to be dynamically dispatched, why make them static? Create an interface and have a list of 15 instances of different classes (or anonymous classes, or lambdas, or whatever) which implement that interface.

Comment: Does this do what you need? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11594797/dynamically-load-a-class-and-invoke-a-method-in-java

Comment: Yeah, but the 15 can be expanded. So I am looking for a solution where I don't have to add a new instance manually

Comment: How would adding an instance be harder than adding a class?

Comment: `clazz.getMethod` reflection method works the same way as `clazz.getConstructor` like in the post you found

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can invoke methods using [reflection](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/javareflection.html):

```
public HashMap<String, String> invoke(int i, int arg0){
    Class<?> clz = Class.forName("package_name.strategy_" + i);
    Method method = clz.getDeclaredMethod("run", int.class);
    return (HashMap<String, String>) method.invoke(null, arg0);
}

for(int i = 0; i < 15; i++){
    HashMap<String, String> output = invoke(i, runDateTimeLocal);
}
```

the name of class for `Class.forName("package_name.strategy_" + i);` must be fully quallified with package name

Answer (score 0):

So what I would do is try making a `Strategy` abstract class, then making all 0 through 15 extend from `Strategy`. Then make a method in `Strategy.java`

```
public static HashMap<String, String> run( ? extends Strategy, Integer i ) {
    Strategy.getResponse() ...
}
```

`? extends Strategy` means any subclass of `Strategy` (in this case Strats 0-15)
Then you would construct it in the main and call

```
Strategy.run( strategyResponse, i)
```

I tried doing what I said here and I can't get it to compile correctly. Instead I made a dummy class to play around with:

```
public class Strategies< T extends AbstractStrategy >
{
    ArrayList<? extends AbstractStrategy> li = new ArrayList<>() ;
    
    public HashMap<String,String> run( Strategies<?> strat ) 
    {
        HashMap<String,String> map = new HashMap<>() ;
        return map ;
    }
    
}
```

both of those compile so you might be able to play around with the syntax a bit to get it to your liking and usage.

Comment: Your initial suggestion won't work for static methods. You need an instance of the class in order to dispatch to the correct implementation.